# Bundler/Minifier for CSS (What's Browserify, Stitch, etc. for JavaScript)?

Tags: css

Is there a lib out there which allows to bundle css files together? As far as I know, there is an **@import** rule defined in the CSS spec to be used like CommonJS require() known from the JS world...

Starting from an entry point, one could then traverse all @import declarations and bundle a single css file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) provides this feature:

[Optimizing one css file](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#onecss)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using commonjs / browserify, you can use [parcelify](https://github.com/rotundasoftware/parcelify) to output a css bundle based on the browserify dependency graph.

Comment: Thanks for this. This also supports using Sass which is amazing.